# Add seleniumlibrary prefix to keyword call issue

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, robotframework, ride

I was facing keyword issue with robot framework and selenium in eclipse. I downgrade robot to 3.2.2 from 4.0 as it is not supporting in RED editor. Now I am facing new issue. I need to add seleniumlibrary prefix manually to all the keywords.
Is there any way to do it quickly as I have around 55 scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your issue, as can be seen in the screenshot, is that you have both `SeleniumLibrary` as well as `Selenium2Library` providing the same keyword for you. The best solution to this would be to remove the `Selenium2Library` altogether, if possible. Unless you have some extremely old scripts done with the old SeleniumLibrary it doesn't provide anything for you.

If both libraries are needed, the `BuiltIn` library provides keyword called `Set Library Search Order` which will resolve the conflicts by using the primary library first and then if the keyword is not found, defaulting to the secondary one. See the keyword documentation [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order).

So it would work like this

```
TC ID : N
    Set Library Search Order    SeleniumLibrary    Selenium2Library
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: That issue now resolved.                                                                                                            I am getting new error.  [ ERROR ] Taking listener 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir5042264645351673193\TestRunnerAgent.py:54844' into use failed: Importing listener 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir5042264645351673193\TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot.parsing.populators'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Either your Robot was partially uninstalled or something else happened but for some reason the robot.parsing.populators is missing. You can try to re-install robot to get the missing files with ``pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>``. If that doesn't help, see that your ``%PYTHONPATH%`` contains path to the robot installation.